# how to pass strings from one activity and display them as a textview in another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

In my application am collecting 2 values from server in 2 strings as,

```
String j1, j2;

j1 = strLine[11];  //Collecting values from the server
j2 = strLine[12];
```

and passing them to another activity,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UserBookAppointSearchList.class);

i.putExtra("J1", j1);
i.putExtra("J2", j2);

startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

And in the other activity, am collecting strings as,

```
TextView tv2;

String j1, j2; // strings to collect values from previous activity

 j1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("J1");
 j2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("J2");

 tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg2);
 tv2.setText(j1+":"+j2);
```

Can anyone tell me what is  wrong with this code??

Comment: getting any exception or error..??

Comment: looks fine. what exactly is not working and what is it currently doing?

Comment: What have you faced ?

Comment: sorry, i forgot add the exception.. am getting Enter proper spellingsjava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:length=11; index=11

Comment: got it.. problem was with declaring array.. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first check whether you are getting anything from server or not.

```
j1 = strLine[11];  //Collecting values from the server
j2 = strLine[12];
Log.d("Getting From Server String 1", j1);
Log.d("Getting From Server String 2", j2);
```

then also try to change the way of getting context.

*this*

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserBookAppointSearchList.class);
```

*to*

```
Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, UserBookAppointSearchList.class);
```

and also print the strings after you fetch them :

```
j1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("J1");
j2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("J2");
Log.d("Getting From Server String 1", j1);
Log.d("Getting From Server String 2", j2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In recieving activity, inside oncreate(), do this to retrieve values :-

```
String j1 = "";
String j2 = ""; // strings to collect values from previous activity
TextView tv2;

        Bundle bundle   = getIntent().getExtras();
        try {
             j1 = bundle.getString("J1");
             j2 = bundle.getString("J2");
        } catch (Exception e) {
             j1 = "";
             j2 = "";
        }

        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg2);
        tv2.setText(j1+":"+j2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Myforgetpassword.class);
                i.putExtra("username", "kiran"));
                startActivity(i);
```

and in second Activity:

```
 Intent i=getIntent();
 String username1 = i.getExtras().getString("username");
```